# Cython rejects float32 in fused dtype

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython

I am trying to write a Cython function that would be able to consume a fused dtype that includes float32. However it rejects the input unless specified explicitly. Why ?

For example:

```
cimport numpy as cnp

ctypedef fused floatdtype:
    cnp.npy_float32

@cy.boundscheck(False)
@cy.wraparound(False)
cpdef void test(floatdtype smth):
    print(smth)
```

And then in Python the below raises "TypeError: No matching signature found" error:

```
import numpy as np

smth= np.float32(19700101.0)
test(smth)
```

However this works just fine:

```
cimport numpy as cnp

@cy.boundscheck(False)
@cy.wraparound(False)
cpdef void test( cnp.npy_float32 smth):
    print(smth)
```

Comment: I think it's probably that the constant is interpreted as a double and it looks for an exact match. A more typical use for fused types would be a type with both float and double defined.